# Reaction of 1-Bromo-1-phenylethene with two equivalents of LDA

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I was confronted with the reaction of 1-bromo-1-phenylethene with two equivalents of LDA, then the product is hydrolyzed.
As it is a bulky base, it will surely deprotonate and form the phenylacetylene, and form phenylacetyl-lithium in a second step, but what happens when it is hydrolyzed?
Will the product stay as it is or what happens?

Comment: The phenyllithium acetylide is a reasonably stable species (pKa mid 20s). Protonation will give phenylacetylene.